# :focus applying styles when textarea not actually in focus

Tags: css, stylus

I have css (stylus) here:

```
.textarea:focus
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 73px 5px primary-color
```

yet the textarea has the box shadow by default. Here is the codepen link:

https://codepen.io/Tycholiz22/pen/vbGMLJ?editors=1100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your styles are stacked in such a way that the default `.textarea` also receives the box-shadow:

```
.textarea

.textarea:focus
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 73px 5px primary-color
```

This renders to

```
.textarea, .textarea:focus {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 73px 5px #09ae96;
}
```

If you remove `.textarea` from the shared style block, you'll see the `:focus` style disappear when unfocused.

Comment: Nice. Just beat me to it!

Comment: The great `CSS` nerd race!

Answer (score 1):

```
.textarea

.textarea:focus
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 73px 5px primary-color
```

In your Stylus code, there is a `.textarea` with no styles applied to it just before the `.textarea:focus` line. This is translating to: `.textarea, .textarea:focus`. **This is because [Stylus interprets a newline as equivalent to selector separators (commas in a rule set).](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html#rule-sets).**

Remove the `.textarea` to fix your code.

See the Chrome inspector:

[image]